# Deletar dados com a relação @ManyToOne

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Como faço para deletar dados com a relação `@ManyToOne`? Ele não dá erro, mas não apaga os dados no banco.

Minha classe `Pedido`:

```
public class Pedido extends GenericDomain{

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Short quantidade;

    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 7, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal precoParcial;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Produto produto;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Venda venda;
```

Minha classe `Venda`:

```
public class Venda extends GenericDomain{


       @Column(nullable = false)

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date horario;

    @Column(nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 2)
    private BigDecimal precoTotal;

    @ManyToOne
    private Cliente cliente;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private Funcionario funcionario;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "venda")
     @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE)
    private List<Pedido> pedido= new ArrayList<Pedido>();
```

No meu DAO:

```
public void excluir(Venda venda, List<Pedido> pedido) {
    Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getFabricaDeSessoes().openSession();
    Transaction transacao = null;

    try {
        transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();      

        for(int posicao = 0; posicao < pedido.size(); posicao++){

            Pedido pedidoVenda = pedido.get(posicao);
            pedidoVenda.setVenda(venda);            
            sessao.delete(sessao.get(Venda.class, pedidoVenda));

        }
        transacao.commit();
    } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
            if (transacao != null) {
                transacao.rollback();
            }
            throw erro;
    } finally {
        sessao.close();
    }
}

}
```

Bean:

```
public void excluir(ActionEvent evento) {
    try {
        venda = (Venda) evento.getComponent().getAttributes().get("vendaSelecionado");

        VendaDAO vendaDAO = new VendaDAO();
        vendaDAO.excluir(venda, pedido);
        vendas = vendaDAO.listar();

        Messages.addGlobalInfo(" Venda removido com sucesso");
    } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
        Messages.addFlashGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar remover a Venda");
        erro.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

XHTML:

```xml
<p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-trash" actionListener="#{vendaBean.excluir}"
    update=":mensagem :formListagem:tabela">
    <p:confirm header="Confirmação" message="Deseja excluir a Venda?"
        icon="ui-icon-alert" />

        <f:attribute name="vendaSelecionado" value="#{venda}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Aqui está o GenericDomain:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GenericDomain implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long codigo;

    public long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }
    public void setCodigo(long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s[codigo=%d]", getClass().getSimpleName(), getCodigo());
    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (codigo ^ (codigo >>> 32));
        return result;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        GenericDomain other = (GenericDomain) obj;
        if (codigo != other.codigo)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: A relação é `@ManyToOne` como você diz no texto ou `@OneToMany` como o código mostra?

Comment: Você pode dar mais detalhes sobre o que há nas classes `Venda` e `Pedido`? Como é a chave delas e como o relacionamento é feito do outro lado?

Comment: é @OneToMany Victor

Comment: o objetivo é apagar uma venda e os pedidos que ela contém, so que com o codigo acima ele não apaga na base de dados nem da erro

Comment: O que há nesse `GenericDomain`?

Comment: O objectivo Victor é eliminar a venda e os respectivos pedidos

Comment: o gericdomain tem o codigo que são atribuidos pelo hibernate

Answer (score 1):

Se voce quer remover somente o produto, seria somente dar update no objeto pedido apontando produto como null, o update de Pedido removeria a entidade produto, e o mapeamento Pedido-Produto nao poder ser nullable=false.

Mas se for para remover o pedido como um todo, basta remover dar o delete na entidade Pedido e mapear com cascade o @ManyToOne, assim:

`@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)`

Answer (score 0):

Se o mapeamento esta corrento,

É assim.

```
objetoPai.getPedido().remove(pedido-a-ser-removido);
sessao.update(objetoPai);
```

Para que o remove funcione da lista precisa ter o hashCode e Equals implementados corretamentes

Comment: os hashCode e Equals estão bem implementados so não apaga na base de dados nem da erro na tela

Comment: "bem implementados!" ja fez debug e viu que o objeto não esta na coleção?
esta usando cascade @Cascade(CascadeType.DELETE), se esta fazendo update, como relatei acima deveria ser de acordo com a ação.
@Cascade(CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE), igual a ação sofrida no objeto pai